# Making a timer to very slightly delay several audio channels for iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, audio, nstimer

I have 5 audio channels being operated by five AVAudioPlayer objects, and I would like to add a very small delay to each of these channels, so that when I push a button, I get this:

- Start sound 1 (which lasts 10 seconds)
- Start sound 2 0.25 seconds after sound 1
- Start sound 3 0.25 seconds after sound 2
- Start sound 4 0.25 seconds after sound 3
- Start sound 5 0.25 seconds after sound 3

I tired to do this just using sleep(0.25) between each calling of [AVAudioPlayerObeject play] like this:

```
[audioPlayer1 play];
sleep(delay);
[audioPlayer2 play];
sleep(delay);
[audioPlayer3 play];
sleep(delay);
[audioPlayer4 play];
sleep(delay);
[audioPlayer5 play];
```

...where delay is a float variable set to 0.25. However, this doesn't work, and I hear all 5 sounds at once. I tried experimenting with NSTimer, but I didn't really understand how to make a separate method for the delay, and then call the method with my code.

Can someone please help me revise my code to get the desired effect? Thanks!

Comment: You could try adding increments of a quarter second's silence to the beginning of each sound, then play them all at once =)

Comment: you need to play the 2nd sound when the 1st sound is playing and then add a delay and play 2nd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep state with an integer that identifies which sound to start...

```
@property(assign, nonatomic) NSInteger startSound;
```

Schedule a timer...

```
self.startSound = 0;
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

When the timer fires, start a new sound.  Quit after you've started 5....

```
- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer {

    if (self.startSound < 5) {
        // assume you know how to play sound N, numbered 0..4
        [self playSound:self.startSound++];
    } else {
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}
```

You can make the timer interval and the max count of sounds variables in this class.